# Securing API key on Github after being pushed

Tags: android, git, github, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have unknowingly uploaded my api key for my app on Github and thus I deleted the api key from [console.developer.google.com](http://console.developer.google.com)

,Did it guarantee me that there will  not be any issue with that api key?

Also ,I want help in how to remove that from all the commits in the project on Github.

Any Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the key and ensure it does not function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did it guarantee me that there will not be any issue with that api key?

Yes, considering the key is deleted from your account. Do test it, as commented.

> I want help in how to remove that from all the commits in the project on Github.

Follow the GitHub guide "[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)".
The [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) can help too.